# Why base current changes with collector emitter voltage?

Tags: common-emitter

There are two questions in stack exchange similar to mine, but I though mine was more basic and also more specific.

I tried doing some SPICE simulations in order to understand transistor characteristics described [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e84/lectures/ch4/node3.html), but using a real transistor, i.e., 2N2222. I tried two circuits as shown below. As you can see, both circuits are very similar with Vbe, Vcc being exactly the same between the two. The only difference is that the one on the right has 100 ohms more between Vcc and the collector. I expected Ib to have the same waveform between the two circuits - but when I saw the simulated waveform, Ib on the right circuit (blue color) seems to different from the Ib of the left circuit (green hiding behind the blue signal for the most part). The red signal is the Vce of the left circuit and the blue green signal is the Vce of the right circuit.

What I have read in many books, literature online (including the one I have referred here), is that Vce has no effect on Ib. And yet, my observation is different! Can anyone kindly explain this strange behavior of Ib? Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Try Google "early effect" or "base width modulation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you saturate Vce (down near zero), the transistor's current gain drops greatly. So the base-emitter junction becomes "just a diode". Green curve hasn't quite reached Vce saturation. Blue curve ventures into saturation.
Perhaps you are trying to investigate the "early effect" as G36 has suggested. This effect addresses a linearly-operating transistor. While your circuit is driving this transistor hard, the green-curve drive is at the very upper edge of linearity. The blue-curve drive is over the edge of linearity.